# Selenium webdriver always headless

Tags: selenium-webdriver, chrome, headless

I am creating a simple webapp that allows my support colleagues to run Selenium Java Code from my custom created API.
When from Eclipse (the app deployed in Tomcat8) I run a script, i can see in my screen that the webbrowser (in this case the chrome webdriver) is opened and I can actually see what is happening in my screen. However, when I just start Tomcat as a windows service (and do not run it from Eclipse), it also run, however it seems to run headless. I would like it to also show me the browser so that I can see what is happening. I can't really find anything on this, so I hope someone can help me out here or give me a pointer.